# Can you differentiate between raw numbers versus quoted numbers for command-line arguments without escaping the quotes in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, console-application, windows-console

For a C# console application, if I provide the following, my parameters will be interpreted as the same value:

```
myapp.exe "0" 0
```

And just be `0` with a length of 1 when inspected.

I was wondering if there's a way to detect a quoted number versus a raw number at command-line for C# console applications without forcing escaping the quotes for the user's input.

I know that you can do this,

```
myapp.exe \"0\" 0
```

And get back `"0" 0` when checking the command-line arguments with `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` such as the example below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace cl_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> arg_list = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList();
            foreach(var arg in arg_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do without quote-escaping? If not, is that a generalized Windows command-line limitation?

Comment: You mean I shouldn't skate by with a single API call? No problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.CommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the command line as a raw string, then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting strings to allow for spaces is the standard Windows command line syntax, not a limitation, just syntax. Additionally escaping quotes with `\` is also standard. This is why .NET tries to be helpful and parses the arguments using these rules in `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` (and `static void Main(string[] args)`).

If you want to override these default behaviour, you will need to parse the raw command line yourself. You get retrieve this from [`Environment.CommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline(v=vs.110).aspx). This returns the actual command line call, so includes the program name, e.g. `ConsoleApplication1.exe  "0" 0`.

Comment: I wouldn't say syntax, it's more a convention. Syntax implies it absolutely has to be followed, but nothing stops you from saying, for example, `app.exe "`. Note that my previous example is not allowed in Linux, where the command interpreter steps in and changes your command line before you even get a chance to look at it (globbing for example).